# Sending email in java but shows that try to connect SMTP

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email using JavaMail, but it does not work. Below is my code. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Here is my controller class responsible for sending email:

```
package com;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MailService {
    private static MailService theService = null;
    private static Session mailSession;
    private static final String HOST = "localhost";
    private static final int PORT =465;
    private static final String USER = "rouaharonnie@gmail.com"; //
    private static final String PASSWORD = "admin"; // 
    private static final String FROM = "rouaharonnie@gmail.com";     
    public static void sendMessage(String recipient, String subject, String message) throws MessagingException {
        if (theService==null) {
            theService = new MailService();
        }
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
        mimeMessage.setSender(new InternetAddress(FROM));
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mimeMessage.setContent(message, "text/plain");
        mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect(HOST,PORT,USER,PASSWORD);
           // transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
    }

    private MailService() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", HOST);
        props.put("mail.smtps.user", USER);
        props.put("mail.smtps.password", PASSWORD);
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.from", FROM);
        props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port",PORT);

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
    }
}
```

But it shows this error when I invoke `sendMessage()` method.

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 465, isSSL true
```

Comment: Did you miss the part that `SMTPSSLTransport`? Because you are using SMTP over SSL.

Comment: I didn't try it with main()method.I want to send email using a form

Comment: Would please check the code and solve this SMTPSSLTransport because I can't fully understand this SMTPSSLTransport?

Comment: Maybe too obvious, but just checking: Do you actually have a SMTP Service running @localhost?

Comment: I did it using tomcat.How I check that it supports  SMTP Service?

Comment: Tomcat is not a mail server.  You need a real mail server.  That will almost always be somewhere else on your network, not on "localhost".  If you're determined to run your own mail server, the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#servers) has some pointers.  You'll also want to fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) in your code.

Comment: how would I run this using localhost?Where should I fix my code?

Comment: Can anyone provide me the right solution for this?Until now I can't fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to send mail just change the bellow code.
I used (smtp.gmail.com) server and change secure app option from off to on  from my account setting in gmail.

```
// here i used real gmail account and password
private static final String USER = "gmailid@gmail.com";                       
private static final String PASSWORD = "admin";
// use this instead of transport.connect(HOST,PORT,USER,PASSWORD)
transport.connect(USER,PASSWORD)
```

All that is work  fine ..good luck anyone who faces the same problem

Answer (score -2):

Try use 587 port and more one thing you must check turn off security in your mailbox and permit untrusted application access to your mailbox